# Copying a dynamically allocated 2D array from host to device in CUDA

Tags: c++, arrays, cuda, fft, dynamic-arrays

I want to copy a dynamically allocated 2D array from host to device to get its Discrete Fourier Transform.

I'm using below code to copy the array to the device

```
cudaMalloc((void**)&array_d, sizeof(cufftComplex)*NX*(NY/2+1));
cudaMemcpy(array_d, array_h, sizeof(float)*NX*NY, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

This works fine with static arrays, i get the intended output from my fft. 
But it doesn't work with dynamic arrays. After little bit searching I learnt I can not copy dynamic arrays like this from host to device. So I found this solution.

```
cudaMalloc((void**)&array_d, sizeof(cufftComplex)*NX*(NY/2+1));
for(int i=0; i<NX; ++i){
    cudaMemcpy(array_d+ i*NY, array_h[i], sizeof(float)*NY, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
}
```

But it's also not doing the task properly since I get wrong values from my fft.

Given below is my fft code.

```
cufftPlanMany(&plan, NRANK, n,NULL, 1, 0,NULL, 1, 0,CUFFT_R2C,BATCH);
cufftSetCompatibilityMode(plan, CUFFT_COMPATIBILITY_NATIVE);
cufftExecR2C(plan, (cufftReal*)data, data);
cudaThreadSynchronize();
cudaMemcpy(c, data, sizeof(float)*NX*NY, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

How can I overcome this problem ?

EDIT

given below is the code

```
#define NX 4
#define NY 5
#define NRANK 2
#define BATCH 10

#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <cufft.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <iostream>

int check();

int main()
    { 


    // static array
    float b[NX][NY] ={ 
        {0.7943 ,   0.6020 ,   0.7482  ,  0.9133  ,  0.9961},
        {0.3112 ,   0.2630 ,   0.4505  ,  0.1524  ,  0.0782},
         {0.5285 ,   0.6541 ,   0.0838  ,  0.8258  ,  0.4427},
         {0.1656 ,   0.6892 ,   0.2290  ,  0.5383  ,  0.1067}
        };

    // dynamic array
    float **a = new float*[NX];     
    for (int r = 0; r < NX; ++r)  
        {
        a[r] = new float[NY];
        for (int c = 0; c < NY; ++c)
            {            
                a[r][c] = b[r][c];           
            }
        }

    // arrray to store the results - host side   
    float c[NX][NY] = { 0 };

    cufftHandle plan;
    cufftComplex *data;
    int n[NRANK] = {NX, NY};

    cudaMalloc((void**)&data, sizeof(cufftComplex)*NX*(NY/2+1));
    cudaMemcpy(data, b, sizeof(float)*NX*NY, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    /* Create a 2D FFT plan. */
    cufftPlanMany(&plan, NRANK, n,NULL, 1, 0,NULL, 1, 0,CUFFT_R2C,BATCH);
    cufftSetCompatibilityMode(plan, CUFFT_COMPATIBILITY_NATIVE);
    cufftExecR2C(plan, (cufftReal*)data, data);
    cudaThreadSynchronize();
    cudaMemcpy(c, data, sizeof(float)*NX*NY, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    cufftDestroy(plan);
    cudaFree(data);

    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: We will need to see a short, complete, compilable example, I think. What is `c` in the FFT code? How is it allocated? is it like `array_h` in the first code? what is `data` in the FFT code? is it the same as `array_d` in the first code? I could go on.

Comment: Most importantly, how is `array_h` defined and initialised?

Comment: sorry. i added the code ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` is of type `cufftComplex` which is series of typedefs eventually resulting in a `float2`. That means `data + n` will advance `data` by `n` objects of type `float2`, or by `2 * n` object of type `float`. This makes your "dynamic array" copying incorrect; you have to halve the increment of `data`.

**EDIT**

Looking at the parameter types of `cufftExecR2C()`, I think this should work:

```
for(int i=0; i<NX; ++i){
  cudaMemcpy(reinterpret_cast<float*>(data) + i*NY, a[i], sizeof(float)*NY, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
}
```

---

Side note: you don't actually have a dynamic 2D array (that would be `new float[NX * NY]`). What you have is a dynamic array of pointers to dynamic arrays of floats. I believe it would make more sense for you to use a true 2D array instead, which would allow you to keep the static-case copy code as well.

And since you've tagged this C++, you should seriously consider using `std::vector` instead of managing your dynamic memory manually. That is, change `a` like this:

```
std::vector<float> a(NX * NY);
```

And while you're at it, I'd suggest turning `NX`, `NY` etc. from macros to constants:

```
const size_t NX = 4;
const size_t NY = 5;
```

etc.

Comment: For the in-place FFT operation in question, the setup and copying of data is completely correct. The library expects the real input to be in contiguous (or pitched linear) floats, and the output is overwritten with twice the amount of input data (ie. N inputs are packed into a 2N length buffer, or the equivalent). There is, in fact, no problem with the code at all. Apart from the fact that only half of the output signal is copied back, it works correctly. The only problem seems to be with the OP interpretation of the results.

Comment: @talonmines The dynamic code copies `NY` floats to position `data`, and then `NY` floats to a position offset by `2 * NY` floats from `data`. The static code does not do that - it copies the inputs contiguously. So they differ, and it's the only difference between the static and dynamic case.

Comment: @Angew : Is this what you mean ? cudaMemcpy(data + 2*i*NY, a[i], sizeof(float)*NY, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); ----  use 2*i*NY instead of i*NY ? But it fails. Actually using cudaMemcpy inside the loop ( the second code snippet I've given in the question) fails even with the static array. How can I solve this ?

Comment: @talonmines : Since this is REAL to COMPLEX fft operation, result of an NxM matrix can be saved in an NxM matrix because of the  Hermitian symmetry. That's how I get the results in the static array scenario.

Comment: @Optimus I actually meant something like `i * NY / 2`. Bear in mind that for `T *p;`, `p + n` moves the pointer by `n * sizeof(T)` bytes. And `data` is a `float2*`, while `*a` is a `float*`.

Comment: @Angew : Ah, only now I understood it. Thanks. But still my problem is not solved :(

Comment: @Optimus How does your original code exactly work, anyway? Your inner arrays are of length 5, which means they store 2-and-a-half complex numbers each. Could that be part of the problem? (Note that I'm addressing this from the code side only, I've unfortunately forgotten most I've ever known of FFT).

Comment: @Angew : As I have mentioned above, since the input is real, output has a some sort of symmetry. So 4x5 matrix is enough to store the result. Actually I get the expected output with the static arrays. The problem is with sending this dynamic array in to the gpu memory properly. Isn't it ?

Comment: @Angew : My original original code calls the fft inside a for loop. at each iteration the matrix size increases and the values are assigned at run time. That's why i need to find the solution for this issue. Actually I'm doing it in a mexfunction and when I do it for a dynamic array Matlab crashes (segmentation error). So now I'm doing it in a normal VS project and once I solve it, I'll move in to my mexfunction.

Comment: @Optimus I've edited the answer a bit. In general, you should first try making it work while treating the static array like the dynamic one. Then the switch from static to dynamic should be trivial.

Comment: @Angew : It worked !!! Thank you for your time. btw do you know any other way of copying the data ? (single function, rather than using a loop - for example using cudaMallocPitch and cudaMemcpy2D )

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44004/discussion-between-optimus-and-angew)